# MS SQL String - HTML breaking/random spaces

Tags: html, sql, string

Good morning

I have an ms sql query which builds an HTML table in a cursor. It's quite a large table (4 cols x > 100 rows).

It seems to be randomly inserting spaces inside some of the table tags like: < /td> - the tag is then being displayed in the output (sending the html/full string to email) rather than rendering the html.

The first 20/30 rows seem to be fine then there are 3 or 4 random tags throughout the table.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Regards,
Ste

Comment: Building HTML in a cursor sounds like my worst nightmare. Why are you doing that in SQL instead of your application code?

Comment: it's not that tricky and seems to work well for fewer records. it's a summary of what records have been 'completed' in the application, so it'll be a sproc running daily as a reminder.

Comment: It's not a question of working well or not. Mixing HTML with SQL is a huge violation of the separation of concerns principle. Presentation layer code (HTML etc.) should be separate from the database code.

Comment: What ZenCoder said. Also impossible to give any tips without seeing any of the code. How could we know where the random spaces come from ?

Comment: thanks for the feedback. i was hoping sql might have been known for it when concatenating a string or something. with regards to separating the code, it makes sense.. what would you suggest for sending scheduled emails to customers?

Comment: we send out hundreds of emails a day, via sql sprocs containing lists of records for the customer to action, or just be informed of as we can't rely on them checking reports or an app

Comment: I'm sure there are commercial programs that can handle this but one way is to just create a command line program and schedule that. Create simple html templates with markers that you replace with data or use something like xsl or even razor engine to create the actual emails to send out. Then schedule the program using whatever scheduler is available on the system you use.